# Mongoose, find, return specific properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this get call:

```
exports.getBIMFromProject = function(req, res){
  mongoose.model('bim').find({projectId: req.params['prj_id']}, function(err, bim){
    if(err){
      console.error(err);
      res.send(500)
    }
    res.send(200, bim);
  });
};
```

Where do I specify which properties I want to return? Can't find it in the docs. The above returns the entire object. I only want a few properties returned.

This is my schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var bimSchema = new Schema({
  projectId: Number,
  user: String,
  items:[
    {
      bimObjectId: Number,
      typeId: String,
      position:{
        floor: String,
        room:{
          name: String,
          number: String
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});

mongoose.model('bim', bimSchema);
```

I don't want the items array included in my rest call.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You use projection. The first example in the [mongoose query docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) has a projection operation tucked in.

NB: not real code b/c I highlighted the important bits with triple stars

```
// find each person with a last name matching 'Ghost', ***selecting the `name` and `occupation` fields***
Person.findOne({ 'name.last': 'Ghost' }, ***'name occupation'***, function (err, person) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('%s %s is a %s.', person.name.first, person.name.last, person.occupation) // Space Ghost is a talk show host.
})
```

The `Person` schema isn't specified but I think the example is clear enough.

Answer (score 54):

Mongoose provides multiple ways to project documents with [`find`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), [`findOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne), and [`findById`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById).

#### 1. Projection as String:

```js
// INCLUDE SPECIFIC FIELDS
// find user and return only name and phone fields
User.findOne({ email: email }, 'name phone');

// EXCLUDE SPECIFIC FIELD
// find user and return all fields except password
User.findOne({ email: email }, '-password');
```

#### 2. Projection by passing `projection` property:

```js
// find user and return just _id field
User.findOne({ email: email }, {
  projection: { _id: 1 }
});
```

#### 3. Using [`.select`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) method:

```js
// find user and return just _id and name field
User.findOne({ email: email }).select('name');

// find user and return all fields except _id
User.findOne({ email: email }).select({ _id: 0 });
```

You can do the same with [`find`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) and [`findById`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) methods too.

Comment: Re (2) the `{projection: {...}}` part doesn't seem to work on my end. It does work if I omit the encapsulating `projection:` field and flatten the contents instead, as in: `User.findOne({ email: email }, { _id: 1 })`

Answer (score 27):

```
MyModel.find({name: "john"}, 'name age address', function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
});
```

This will return fields - `name`, `age` and `address` only.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `.select()` this is possible.

- If number of fields required are less from total fields then,
  `.select('projectId user')` can be used
- Else number of fields to be ignored are less from total fields then,
  `.select('-items')` can be used.

So for getting a field, simply, space separated string of fields can be passed and for ignoring the field, space separated string with "-" before the field can be used.

For [more documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select).

Answer (score 2):

Find Specific properties also avoid some properties

```
await User.find({ email: email }, { name: 1, phone: 1, status: 1, password: 0 });
```

Answer (score 1):

`.Select()` method is used to select which fields are to be returned in the query result

```
let result = await MyModel.find({ user : "user" }).select('name lastname status')
```