# MongoDB and NodeJS write array of objects from mongodb to a json file

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb, object

I need to write an array of places to a JSON file, I take the places from the MongoDB. The code below work

```
'use strict';
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
const debug = require('debug')('myproject:server');
const Place = require('../models/place.js');
const path = './public/places.json';


Place.find({
    reviewed: true
  }, (err, places) => {
    if (err) {
      debug(err);
    } else {
      jsonfile.writeFile(path, places, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          debug(err);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

This is what a single object in the JSON file looks like

```
{ _id: 58b8d11cbaa41f288236d5fa,
  __v: 0,
  mainImg: 'placeImg-1490464803517.jpg',
  reviewed: true,
  date: 2017-03-03T02:12:44.313Z,
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum illo odit animi architecto.',
  coord: { lng: 2.166948616504669, lat: 41.382971076851476 },
  type: 'museum',
  title: 'Lorem' }
```

Since I have a lot of objects in the array `places` it makes sense to remove the properties that are not used on the client side, such as `__v` and `reviewed`

I tried doing following before writing array to the file

```
let shorterPlaces = [];
places.forEach((el, i) => {
  delete el['__v'];
  delete el['reviewed'];
  shorterPlaces.push(el);
});
```

and then writing `shorterPlaces` to a file, but the properties remained.

When I tried logging out the object keys inside the for each loop with `console.log(Object.keys(el));` I got `[ '$__', 'isNew', 'errors', '_doc' ]` which does not make any sense to me. Is there something that I am missing here or unaware of?

Comment: The code that `delete`s properties looks fine to me, can you show how you used this modification?

Comment: You can use projection to remove the fields from the response. Something like `Place.find({
    reviewed: true
  }, '-__v -reviewed', (err, places) ....`

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari the properties are not removed with `delete`

Comment: @Veeram can you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose, find, return specific properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330555/mongoose-find-return-specific-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the file you're `require`ing it looks like you're using Mongoose.  Mongoose collection's `find` method returns [Mongoose documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js), which are objects with their own methods and getters/setters, rather than just the plain data in the database.

If you want just the data in a regular JS object, you need to use [`lean`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean):

```
Place.find({ reviewed: true })
  .lean()
  .exec((err, places) => {
     // Here, places will be an array of plain objects that you can
     // manipulate as normal
   })
```