# Mongoose find return only exact property from object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find

I am using Mongoose with MongoDB and i have found this problem. I find one object in database, then i return only the object property, but when i call the variable it returns whole object not the wanted property.

```
var CharacterInDbCounter = await UserModel.findOne({battletag: req.user.battletag}, function(err, user){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        return user.characters
    }
})
console.log(CharacterInDbCounter);
```

returns:

```
{ _id: 5a25a14a05656b24accfe231,
  id: 1234,
  battletag: 'Something',
  provider: 'bnet',
  __v: 0,
  characters:
   [ 5a25a14a05656b24accfe218,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe219,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe21a,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe21b,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe21c,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe21d,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe21e,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe21f,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe220,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe221,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe222,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe223,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe224,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe225,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe226,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe227,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe228,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe229,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe22a,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe22b,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe22c,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe22d,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe22e,
     5a25a14a05656b24accfe22f ] }
```

Comment: You should look at this answer to find out how to have MongoDB return only what your are interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330555/mongoose-find-return-specific-properties

Comment: I have tried this, but eventho i used the parameter for selecting what i actually want, it always returned me an object with _id and characters

Comment: _id comes by default unless you say `_id:0` in the projection parameter

Comment: I think this is another way how to do it. Dont know which is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal you must do it in [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) way

```
var CharacterInDbCounter = await UserModel.findOne({battletag: req.user.battletag})
    .then(function(user){
        return user.characters
    })
console.log(CharacterInDbCounter);
```

Unfortunately when you use `await` you cannot `catch` errors by promise `catch`, you must surround your code in `try/catch` to catch exception and inside `then` check if `user` argument is not undefined or empty

```
try {
    var CharacterInDbCounter = await UserModel.findOne({battletag: req.user.battletag})
        .then(function(user) {
            if (!user) {
                // user not found
            }
            return user.characters
        })
    console.log(CharacterInDbCounter);

} catch(e) {
    // catch unexpected errors
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, as the last thing i want to know is how to debug any error through .then, because if i use function(err,user) doesnt work.

Comment: Like this?                 var CharacterInDbCounter = await UserModel.findOne({battletag: req.user.battletag})
                .then(function(user){
                    return user.characters
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    return "err";
                });

Comment: How its possible, that this error handeling works in the method above                 var CharacterToSaveCounter = await CharacterModel.count({owner: req.user.battletag}, function(err, count){
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        return count;
                    }
                })