# Filter out unwanted data from Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, restify

I am working on a service which uses restify and mongoose as odm.
Below is the service response which I get after DB call.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5a548b7c025cfcffdd286e0f",
        "createdAt": "2018-01-09T09:29:32.515Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-01-09T10:59:49.159Z",
        "subject": "Hello buddy.",
        "body": "i am good and fine.",
        "category": "email service",
        "category_id": "232",
        "author": "5a5485834c2274ce5d5e54f8",
        "__v": 0,
        "images": [
            "https://google.com"
        ],
        "email content": [
            {
                "_id": "5a549dcb80a16b2e822357ae",
                "createdAt": "2018-01-09T10:47:39.883Z",
                "updatedAt": "2018-01-09T10:47:39.883Z",
                "body": "my first comment",
                "name": "asdf"
                "password":"312312"
                "__v": 0,
                "photos": []
            }
        ]
}]
```

```js
Emails.find({_id: emaiId, author_id: author_id}).
                populate('emailcontent').exec(function(err, listOfEmails) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return next(
                        new errors.InvalidContentError(err.errors.name.message),
                    );
                }
                res.send(listOfEmails);
                next();
```

This is a small part of my response. Now, I do not want to send all the response back to the client. For example, username, password, phone no etc.  So I have a lot of data which I do not want to send back. How do I do this in over here?

Answer (score 0):

Delete these fields manually before sending data back:

```
listOfEmails.forEach(email => {
  // for array properties
  email['email content'].forEach(content => {
    delete content.name;
    delete content.password;
    // ... and so on
  });
  // for usual properties
  delete email._id;
});

res.send(listOfEmails);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array that you send as response. Use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to delete fields.

```js
const newListOfEmails = listOfEmails.map((email) => {
  delete email._id;
  delete email.createdAt;
  delete email.updatedAt;

  for (let eIdx = 0; eIdx < email["email content"].length; eIdx += 1) {
    delete email["email content"][eIdx].password;
  }

  return email;
});

res.send(newListOfEmails);
```

Comment: this code is not deleting. Posts.find({category_id: categoryId}).
    populate('author').exec(function(err, listOfPosts) {
        if (err) {
           console.error(err);
             return next(new errors.InvalidContentError(err.errors.name.message),
    );
   };
   delete listOfPosts.createdAt;
   res.send(200, listOfPosts);})});

Comment: @user3336194 You have to create a new array with map and then delete the items inside the map function. You then send the new array in res.send.

Answer (score 0):

Answers above are about black listing fields, but you can also try whitelisting, e.g.

`const croppedEmails = emails.map( (email) => {
    body: email.body,
    ...(rest of needed fields)
});`

With this approach when you will add new field which is confidential you will not have to add new delete, on the other hand when adding new public field you will also need to add it to above function.

Oh, and there is also projection [Mongoose, find, return specific properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330555/mongoose-find-return-specific-properties)