# How do you use column projection in a Mongoose collection.find query? The documented method does not work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, projection

The following query returns all non-command queries in the profile table of my DB.  I tried to ask it not include the command column using what the Mongoose documentation suggests and my returned object still has the command column.

I also tried "op : 1", which should return ONLY the op column but returned everything still.  I also tried another thing suggested by documentation:  "op -command" and everything was still returned.

Why is this not working?  I tried the same syntax on non-system tables and it also does not work.

```
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
            mongoose.connection.db.collection("system.profile").find( {op : { $ne : "command" }}, { command : 0 }).toArray(function(err, modelOut) 
            {
                if (err) 
                {
                    throw err;
                }
                else
                {  
                    resolve(modelOut);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: This is categorically false, they just aren't schema regulated.  You can still project specific columns/properties from the documents in the collection.  I can do it just fine from Mongo's native drivers, Mongoose is the issue here.

Comment: can we see a sample document?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25332607/2282634