# MongoDB - Returning only one matching array element from Object

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

One of my project collection.

```
{
    "id": {
       "$oid": "5f4600ab7ec81f6c20f8608d"
    },
    "name": "2",
    "category": "2",
    "description": "2",
    "deadline": "2020-08-10",
    "createdBy": {
        "$oid": "5f5089a2265ec85b896f848f"
    },
    "__v": 116,
    "todos": [{
        "time": {
            "$date": "2020-09-10T06:15:36.168Z"
        },
        "doneAt": {
            "$date": "2020-09-10T16:51:53.534Z"
        },
        "done": true,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f59c4f53f0095593b2ace25"
        },
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5f3fcbcae5efa018cc3c9b9d"
        },
        "text": "ooooooo"
    }, {
        "time": {
            "$date": "2020-09-05T13:11:14.139Z"
        },
        "doneAt": null,
        "done": false,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f538f1eeef4d614830e843c"
        },
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5f5089a2265ec85b896f848f"
        },
        "text": "11"
    }],
    "bugs": [{
        "time": {
            "$date": "2020-09-09T03:30:45.463Z"
        },
        "fixedAt": null,
        "fixed": false,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f584f152c5530129ff36ea2"
        },
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5f3fcbcae5efa018cc3c9b9d"
        },
        "text": "new bug"
    }, {
        "time": {
            "$date": "2020-09-06T09:35:12.848Z"
        },
        "fixedAt": null,
        "fixed": false,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f54e1220297a57896646e98"
        },
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5f3fcbcae5efa018cc3c9b9d"
        },
        "text": "4"
    }, {
        "time": {
            "$date": "2020-09-06T09:35:12.848Z"
        },
        "fixedAt": null,
        "fixed": false,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f54e0fc0297a57896646e97"
        },
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5f3fcbcae5efa018cc3c9b9d"
        },
        "text": "5"
    }],
    "members": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f57725977ead80a566855e4"
        },
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5f3fcbcae5efa018cc3c9b9d"
        }
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f576452fe05ec34a1bc487b"
        },
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5f4c8654f4b8c6671d5926ac"
        }
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f562a971e16aa39ca290391"
        },
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5f5089a2265ec85b896f848f"
        }
    }]
}
```

There are more project collection. I put only one here. My goal is retrive one bug element
such as

```
{
        "time": {
            "$date": "2020-09-09T03:30:45.463Z"
        },
        "fixedAt": null,
        "fixed": false,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f584f152c5530129ff36ea2"
        },
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5f3fcbcae5efa018cc3c9b9d"
        },
        "text": "new bug"
    }
```

Every project collection and bug element has own id. I just want to retrieve one bug element from an bugs array in project object using mongoose.

Every project object has similar structure.

Comment: there are so many similar questions, you can do this way [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/trruDTz5nUp)

Comment: I want to use mongoose

Comment: What @turivishal showed in the playground is using a projection.  See [Mongoose, find, return specific properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330555/mongoose-find-return-specific-properties)