# Mongoose get Object out an Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

is my first question here.
My Problem is i want to get an Object contact with _id out of an array contacts: { type: [contactSchema] in an Object Customer. But i get the hole Object Customer.

```
router.route('/customers/:id/contact/:contacts_id').get((req, res) => {
    Customer.findOne({
            "_id": req.params.id,
            "contacts._id": req.params.contacts_id
        },
        (err, customer) => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                res.json(customer);
        }
    )
})
```

And if i use Contact.findOne i get null out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
router.route('/customers/:id/contact/:contacts_id').get((req, res) => {
    Customer.findOne({
            "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
            "contacts._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.contacts_id)
        },
        (err, customer) => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                res.json(customer);
        }
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are querying Customers, your query will return a Customer object. Hoever, using [projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330555/mongoose-find-return-specific-properties), you can hide properties of the object returned by the query. On top of that, [elemmatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) can be used to find a matching item in an array

Here would be how to use those in your case:

```js
Customer.findOne(
  {_id: req.params.id},
  { projection: { _id: 0, contacts: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.params.contacts_id } } },
  (err, customer) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else res.json(customer);
  }
)
```